# Average Neural Network performance varying dependent upon how many folds used in KFold cross validation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn, k-fold

This is my first time using KFold with a Neural Network, and I am struggling to understand why the performance significantly changes dependent upon the number of folds.

I am worried that there is an error in my code and maybe I am missing something. The code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

df = pd.read_csv('../xxx/xxx')

X = df.drop('Dependent', axis=1).values
y = df['Dependent'].values

kf = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=101)

oos_y = []
oos_pred = []

fold = 0
for train, test in kf.split(X):
    fold+=1
    print(f'Fold #{fold}')
    
    X_train = X[train]
    y_train = y[train]
    X_test = X[test]
    y_test = y[test]
    
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
    X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)
    
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(units=936, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    
    model.add(Dense(units=468, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    
    model.add(Dense(units=1))
    
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
    
    early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',
                          mode='min',
                          verbose=0,
                          patience=25)
    
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, 
              validation_data=(X_test, y_test),
              batch_size=128,
              verbose=0, 
              epochs=400,
             callbacks=[early_stop])
    
    pred = model.predict(X_test)
    
    oos_y.append(y_test)
    oos_pred.append(pred)
    
    score = r2_score(pred, y_test)
    print(f'Fold score (r2): {score}')
    
oos_y = np.concatenate(oos_y)
oos_pred = np.concatenate(oos_pred)
score = r2_score(oos_pred, oos_y)
print(f'Final, out of sample score (r2): {score}')
```

I have ran this code with the number of splits being 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, and 30 with the performances being: 0.77, 0.72, 0.79, 0.80, 0.79, and 0.76 respectively. Specifically, at 10 folds the performance seems to dip significantly, which is confusing as checking this against different machine learning algorithms with the same splits and dataset did not reproduce this trend. I'd be grateful if anyone could potential explain the sudden dip in performance at 10 folds, or additional point out errors in the code!

The majority of the code was obtained through following this [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=maiQf8ray_s), adding the scaler and early stopping in myself.

Answer (score 0):

If you look closer to what cross validation is, its normal to have different results for different *k* values.

In particular if you have 100 data points, a 10 fold will create folds using 90 elements for train and 10 for test.
If you change the number of folds to 20, the test part will be smaller, while the testing will be greater,  95 and 5 respectively.

With this in mind the average accuracy varies because the data you are using is changing in dimention itself.
They directly affect the examples the network has available for training, and the number of examples used for testing.

One thing you should consider when choosing the *k* value is the dimention of your dataset, for a big one you can think of a *k* >= 10 but remeber that this means you will be using less than 10% as test set for each fold. Which might lead to wrong assumption on the validity of the results.